# Conveter função PHP para JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Não tenho muito conhecimento de JavaScript. Preciso converter essa verificação abaixo que está em PHP para JavaScript.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
$verificao = $_POST['verificacao_name']; 
$pesquisa1 = $_POST['p1']; 
$pesquisa2 = $_POST['p2'];

if (($verificacao == 2) and
   (($pesquisa1 <= 8 and $pesquisa1 != 0) or  
    ($pesquisa2 <= 8 and $pesquisa2 != 0) or  
    ($pesquisa3 <= 8 and $pesquisa3 != 0))) {
       echo 'Erro'; 
else{
       echo 'Ok'; 
}
```

Comment: E o `$_POST['verificacao_name'];` é o quê em JavaScript?

Comment: É um select pra sim ou não. Se ele escolhe sim tem que executar a função, se escolhe Não, não precisa executar. Desculpa não comentar isso :/

Comment: E o que queres verificar nesse select? o que é `'p1'`?

Comment: Acho que seria melhor dizer o que queres fazer em JavaScript.

Comment: P1 é um valor de 1 a 10. Se ele escolhe verificação = 1 (sim), ele tem que executar aquele if que citei na pergunta. Se for <=8 não deixa passar, tem que retornar false.

Comment: Eu preciso fazer aquele if em JavaScript, entendeu?

Comment: E de onde vem esse `P1` do select também? podes mostrar o objeto que seria o `$_POST`?

Comment: Com os dados vindo via post

Comment: O if é exatamente igual... a pergunta é o que queres fazer em vez de `echo`.

Comment: Como assim _"dados vindos via post"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado as informações incompletas, assumo que queira verificar valores preenchidos em `inputs`, abaixo segue um e é quase idêntico ao `PHP`:

```js
function verificar() {
  var verificacao = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("verificacao_name")[0].value);
  var pesquisa1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("p1")[0].value);
  var pesquisa2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("p2")[0].value);
  var pesquisa3 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("p3")[0].value);

  if (
    (verificacao == 2) && (
      (pesquisa1 <= 8 && pesquisa1 != 0) ||
      (pesquisa2 <= 8 && pesquisa2 != 0) ||
      (pesquisa3 <= 8 && pesquisa3 != 0)
    )
  ) {
    console.log("Ok");
  } else {
    console.log("Erro");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verificacao_name" />
<input type="text" name="p1" />
<input type="text" name="p2" />
<input type="text" name="p3" />

<input type="button" value="Verificar" onClick="javascript:verificar();">
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, exatamente isso. Só converter o que está em PHP para JavaScript.

Comment: Lembre-se que se essas informações forem enviadas para o servidor, é imprescindível a validação dos dados também do lado dele e não somente no cliente.

Comment: Sim, já fazia isso.